# Laravel Consulta dinámica en Query Buider

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de crear una consulta con el facade DB de forma dinámica, según algunos datos que me llegan por la petición, así:

```
// Creamos la consulta según los requisitos solicitados
$operatorsQuery = "DB::table('operators')";
// Por estado
if ($estado == 'A') // Activos
{
    $operatorsQuery .= "->whereNull('deleted_at')";
} elseif ($estado == 'I') {// Inactivos
    $operatorsQuery .= "->whereNotNull('deleted_at')";
} // Todos es el comportamiento por defecto.
// Por rango
$operatorsQuery .= "->where('rango', '>=', '".$rangoLimite1."')";
$operatorsQuery .= "->where('rango', '<=', '".$rangoLimite2."')";
// Por nombre
$operatorsQuery .= "->where('nombre', 'like', '%".$nombre."%')";
// Por ciudad
if ($ciudad != '')
{
    $operatorsQuery .= "->where('ciudad', '".$ciudad."')";
}
// Ordenación
$operatorsQuery .= "->orderByRaw('".$criterioDeOrden." ".$sentidoDeOrden."')";
// Cierre de la consulta
$operatorsQuery .= "->get();";
```

La consulta se crea bien... como una cadena de texto. El problema es a la hora de ejecutarla. He probado lo siguiente:

```
$resultados = eval($operatorsQuery);
```

Pero no funciona. Siempre devuelve `null`.

De que modo se puede crear y ejecutar así una consulta dinámicamente?
Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario complicar la ejecución (y la lectura del código) de una consulta sencilla con eval y cadenas de texto, la solución es aprovechar  la flexibilidad de los objetos y en este caso Laravel, por cierto, no olvidar el uso correcto de PSR-2 y de las comillas simples o dobles:

```
$query = DB::table('operators');

if ($estado == 'A') {
    $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
} elseif ($estado == 'I') {
    $query->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
}

$query->where('rango', '>=', $rangoLimite1);

$query->get();
```

Comment: Gracias. Tu solución no sólo funciona perfectamente, si no que, además, queda un código mucho más limpio y entendible. Genial